# Check for http or https

Tags: http, encryption, https

I am using a proxy extension in chrome **(Zenmate)**. They are saying that they **encrypting** each and every request. But I want to cross check it, that all the requests are **HTTPS** or some are **HTTP** too. I there any tool to check??
Thanks

Comment: There's a network tab in the Chrome dev tools. You could look there.

Comment: But by seeing on that we can't say that the data is encrypted or not.
Can u please suggest me other options..

Comment: If it's going to https, it's encrypted. If not, it's not. You can also use Wireshark or another tool to monitor all the traffic coming from and going to your machine.

Comment: Actually I used Smartsniff to check that it is showing most of the request as https and only one or two to be http. I m only checking for TCP protocol in that. What can i infer from that?? Is the (Zenmate) not able to encrypt the whole data??

Comment: Not necessarily. It could well be that there are other applications (not Chrome) sending traffic over http. I'd try to hunt down the origin of the non-secure requests (the uris being hit might provide a clue), and go from there.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply.  but I was closing all other application like firefox,ie, windows update and even I have disabled the plugins like players and all in Chrome.